# Write .net core Az Function App to return large file data for consumption of Logic App HTTP Connector with chunking enabled

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, dotnet-httpclient

How to properly handle a call from logic app HTTP connector that has chunking enabled to send multiple chunks of data as it gets read by the az func app?

I found an example of a [nodejs](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/sample-api-that-support-logic-app-chunking-using-node-js/ba-p/2560452) example but is there something equivalent for C#? Can I use Az Func or a durable function instead of setting up a server?

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AzFuncApp
{
    public class GetChunkedDocumentFromServer
    {
        private readonly ILogger<GetChunkedDocumentFromServer> _logger;

        public GetChunkedDocumentFromServer(ILogger<GetChunkedDocumentFromServer> log)
        {
            _logger = log;
        }

        [FunctionName("GetChunkedDocumentFromServer")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            string url = req.Headers["url"];

            string absFilePath = @"500mb.docx";
            var stream = File.Exists(absFilePath) ? File.OpenRead(absFilePath) : null;


            byte[] buffer = new byte[104857600]; // 100MB 
            while (true) //loop to the end of the file
            {
                // i assume some response to logic app needs to happen here after reading a chunk
                int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); //read each chunk
                if (read <= 0) //check for end of file
                    break;
                _logger.LogDebug(buffer.ToString());
            }


            // how to return data?
            var result = "OK";
            return new OkObjectResult(result);
        }

    }
}
```

**What I've tried**

I tried fetching the large file from a storage account directly from Logic App but due to the size limit, logic app recommends using a connector with chunking. That's why I'm looking to create a Az func app that will get the file data and send it to logic app as chunks.